# Auto compilation and script replacing

Tags: compilation

Basically i have script that i should compile and replace with old compiled script. I can compile script if i move it on file compile.exe. Problem that compile.exe move my new compiled script to another fodder. And my old compiled script placed in another, third fodder. So basically i should to od next:

I have script in fodder1 and old_compiled_script in fodder3. I need to move script on compile.exe to compile script to new_compiled_script. Compile.exe will place new_compiled_script in fodder2. And after that i need to move new_compiled_script in fodder3 and in fodder3 replace new_compiled_script with old_compiled_script.

That's not that hard if do it once, but i do it over 500 times per day and it becames annoying.

So the question is next, can i make it all authomatically if i know places of all scripts, fodders and compile.exe. Will be better if somebody will show me a little example of it.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the language you have written your script in?

Comment: sourcepawn (.sp) After compilation it becames to .smx

Comment: You should tag your question appropriately.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter what language or script i use. It could be not a script at all. I need just make few actions authomatically. Move file on file and replace new file with old file. So file can have any type.

Comment: OK, still you can do something to improve the tagging. After 3 hours you had only 16 views, that's not good. Is it about Visual Studio? Eclipse? Add appropriate tagging and you'll have more people looking at your problem.